# Having two dropdown menus in the same nav bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As Im saying in the title of the question, I created a navigation bar with two dropdown boxes. The problem is when im trying to open one menu with hover (it worked perfectly with one dropdown box only), the second one opens the same time. This is the script I created. Any suggestion would be very happily accepted!

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".dropdown").hover(
      function () {
    $("ul.dropdown-menu").slideDown("medium").stop(true,true);
      }, 
      function () {
    $("ul.dropdown-menu").slideUp("medium").stop(true,true);
      }  
    );
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `$("ul.dropdown-menu")` is a jQuery object representation of all `ul` elements that are of classe `dropdown-menu`. The same goes to `$(".dropdown")`.

You can use [`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to solve this problem.

> Iterate over a jQuery object, executing a function for each matched
>   element.

In the callback function, use `$(this)`to access each jQuery object and [`:eq`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) to get the nth object of `$("ul.dropdown-menu")` (it is 0-based so the first object is `:eq(0)`). 
.

```
var a =0;
$(".dropdown").each(function(){
   var b = a;
   $(this).hover(function () {
      $("ul.dropdown-menu:eq("+b+")").slideDown("medium").stop(true,true);
   }, function() {
      $("ul.dropdown-menu:eq("+b+")").slideUp("medium").stop(true,true);
   });
   a++;
});
```

Comment: I used it but the dropdown list does not open

Comment: @user3469716 I just updated the code. I made some careless mistakes just now.

Comment: so the mistake was the ul. in front of dropdown?

Comment: @user3469716 When you do `$(ul.dropdown-menu)` you are selecting the two `ul`s at the same time so of course both will open when you mouse over `$(".dropdown")`.

Comment: @user3469716 I just fixed another careless mistake in my code. Now it will work just as you want it to be.

Comment: @user3469716 You are welcome. By the way the mistake wasn't because of the "ul." in front of "dropdown" but because `$("something")` will give you all elements that match "something". So in this case, `$("ul.dropdown-menu")` give you 2 elements instead of 1.

Comment: @user3469716 What I did is `$("ul.dropdown-menu:eq(0)")` which gives you only the first element.

Comment: @user3469716 And it is in a loop with variable b (as the zero that is ever-increasing) so I set the 1st dropdown to only affect `$("ul.dropdown-menu:eq(0)")` and the 2nd dropdown to only affect `$("ul.dropdown-menu:eq(1)")`. The loop (or you can call it iteration) is created by `.each()`.

Comment: Now I understand exactly how it works... Thanks for the explanation too!

Answer (score 0):

Provide each dropdown menu with id and call .hover() by the id like this

```
$("#firstDropdown").hover();
$("#secDropdown").hover();
```